# Joomla 2.5! How can i customize own template for category layout?

Tags: templates, layout, joomla, joomla2.5

I am designing a template. With Beez_2 template, articles are able to display under blog layout, but with my own template, they are only able to able to display under list layout. How can i customize own template to display articles in a category under blog/list layout?.. Thank. I am using joomla 2.5!

Answer (score 0):

Check your templates' /templates/some_template/html/com_content/category folder: there should be at least two files, "default.php" and "blog.php", if you only have default, the blog view may not be available.

For testing, just rename "category" to something else and you should see the default blog available again.

Comment: I don't mean override com_content in my own template. I think i need some css files to format those.I found postition.css in Beez_20 template.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand: are you asking how to edit the css files in your own template?

Comment: I mean, with default template Beez_20,featured articles are able to display in 2 or 3,... columns, but it doesn't work with my template (they display under a list).First i am not sure how. But now i figure out that we must customize my some css file in own template.

Comment: it sounds like it's css-related, are the divs floated (float:left)?

Comment: True, it 's css-related.Because com_content of joomla core generates a lot of tags with various class,id. So I think we must rely those tags to styling.

Comment: Ok, make sure you have firebug installed on firefox.  Right-click on the article, choose "Inspect with Firebug" and find its containing div could be something like <div class="item" or the like.  Create a rule for it (right click on the right handside and choose add new rule).  The rule should be something like div.item {float:left; width:30%; border:1px dashed red} add the border so you're sure you're targeting the right divs, once you get the size padding floats ok, remove the border, and copy the new rule to your custom.css

Comment: Thank a lot  @Riccardo Zorn!

Comment: @TrầnMinh if Riccardo helped you as your comment seems to indicate it would be appropriate to up-vote and mark as answer.